# Is there a way to run spring-shell 2.x in a non interactive mode

Tags: spring, spring-shell

We are building a spring-shell application. currently, in interactive mode, I have to go like

```
java -jar sample.jar
```

> shell:> mycommand arg1 agr2

is there a way to run this nun interactively,
Something like this

`java -jar sample.jar mycommand arg1 agr2` and then exit.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/pull/189

Answer (score 1):

You can add this custom runner to your application and it will work.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/c3081d260e7f797f3f2ccd77aedd7decc385d536/spring-shell-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/samples/ExampleApplicationRunnerConfiguration.java